# How to check if my device is owned on MDM?

Tags: macos, mdm

I previously registered my personal device with MDM, specifically Microsoft Intune (aka Company Portal) - it installed a bunch of software like Zscaler (and its root certificate) and a lot of Microsoft apps. I regretted it and I want to uninstall it.

I followed the uninstall instructions at [Remove device from Company Portal for macOS app](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/user-help/unenroll-your-device-from-intune-macos) and uninstalled the Company Portal App, removed Zscaler root certificate and Microsoft apps, and also that the `Profiles` section is gone from System Preferences.

Unfortunately, whenever I restart the mac, I see a message below the lock screen: "Welcome to CompanyName". Without restarting, it doesn't show up on the normal lock screen, and I have confirmed that system preferences isn't configured with a lock screen message.

What can I do to disable this message, or this persistent form of MDM.

Comment: Hunting down the log in message is a small part of the cleanup required. Did you have backups that are current and include the machine before you enrolled in MDM?

Comment: Thanks! No I don't have backups. What backup technique would you recommend? I wonder what else is not cleaned up after removing MDM . I'll have to do a clean install.

Comment: I love time machine - to a USB drive. They put log in banners, unlikely there’s any spy stuff, but they could have. Look for things like backup software, data loss prevention software, other network filters, etc…

Comment: Im going to make my answer more general - your personal device almost certainly isn’t enrolled in Apple School or Business Manager just by opting to enroll in a MDM, but others may have devices that are and make use of your Q and A here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is typical and consistent with two things:

1. MDM profiles loaded on your OS have been removed - profiles is where Apple lets you know the OS is currently managed and can be controlled.
2. All the changes the MDM made are not likely removed or reverted,  it some will be removed when the profile is deleted.
3. The machine may still be enrolled in automatic management by the company (which can force re-enrollment when it activates in the future) through [Apple Business Manager](https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-business-manager/intro-to-apple-business-manager-axmd344cdd9d/web) or [Apple School Manager](https://www.apple.com/education/k12/it/)

To clean up after removing MDM, you want to follow the steps for your hardware and your macOS level to erase and reinstall a clean OS. Also confirm the company or school has released the device serial number from enrollment if you are taking ownership of the device from them.