# M1 MacBook Pro EFI Lock system PIN unlock situation on Monterey OS update

Tags: apple-silicon, efi

My M1 MacBook suddenly rebooted and locked asking for 6 digit system pin. I think it happened during macOS Monterey update on a public WiFi. Apple store didn't help as they couldn't confirm the purchase mentioning that I bought it on eBay and now I've a big brick at hand. I'm looking to erase everything and re-install a fresh copy of the macOS to avoid similar situations in future. Much appreciate your guidance and help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you edit your post to describe your ideal outcome here? [Looking to erase everything?](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455) Something else you want to do or [some other context](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/442152/5472) or what Apple store told you was going on and why they couldn’t help bypassing s passcode lock?

Comment: Thanks @bmike and will edit the post now.

Comment: Try and follow my steps in the linked answer. If this was stolen goods, you might have issues getting the original owner to release the device. If it’s legitimately sold, you can contact that owner and they ran release the serial number instantly once they want to release this Mac. File a dispute with eBay sooner in case your goods were not as described.

Comment: Thanks @bmike and let me follow the steps and will report back here.